# return a string based on a case when statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, coalesce

So i have two tables

I was wondering if anyone could help. So in my main table I have strings that have different formats.

Mac address are getting populated as the meter but it they are still linked in another table.

What is the best way to clean this data in bigquery to pull back the desired results of just the meters inplace of the mac addresses?

I have tried this so far but I'm not getting any results back, and I'm still getting mac address back where the meter should be?
The thing with the left join table is im also trying to return the MAP ID so long as the meter and L_meter join together too.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(table2.L_METER,METER) AS METER,
    MAP.map_id AS Map,

FROM `table1 ` AS A
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS MAP ON METER = L_METER
                            AND METER = MAP.mac_address
```

**Main Table**

| METER |
| --- |
| G4F00113102000 |
| 904DC300000RE122 |
| 904DC3000001E131 |
| G4F00191402000 |
| G4F00610542000 |

**Left join table**

| L_METER | mac_address | MAP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E6S15544342061 | 904DC3000001E131 | SSL |
| G4F00111072000 | 904DC300000RE122 | SMP |
| G4F00113102000 | 904DC3000001T133 | SMP |
| G4F00191402000 | 904DC3000001Y144 | SMP |
| G4F00610542000 | 904DC3000001U55 | SMP |

**Desired Results**

| METER |
| --- |
| G4F00113102000 |
| G4F00111072000 |
| E6S15544342061 |
| G4F00191402000 |
| G4F00610542000 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `COALOESCE()` with left join. If `table1.METER=table2.mac_address` then `L_METER` will be selected otherwise `L_METER` will be NULL and `METER` will be selected.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table1 (METER varchar(20));
 insert into table1 values('G4F00113102000');
 insert into table1 values('904DC300000RE122');
 insert into table1 values('904DC3000001E131');
 insert into table1 values('G4F00191402000');
 insert into table1 values('G4F00610542000');
 
 
 create table table2(L_METER    varchar(20),mac_address varchar(20));
 insert into table2 values('E6S15544342061','904DC3000001E131');
 insert into table2 values('G4F00111072000','904DC300000RE122');
 insert into table2 values('G4F00113102000','904DC3000001T133');
 insert into table2 values('G4F00191402000','904DC3000001Y144');
 insert into table2 values('G4F00610542000','904DC3000001U55');
```

Query:

```
 select coalesce(table2.L_METER,METER) METER
 from table1 left join table2
 ON table1.METER=table2.mac_address
```

Output:

| METER |
| --- |
| G4F00113102000 |
| G4F00111072000 |
| E6S15544342061 |
| G4F00191402000 |
| G4F00610542000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=661d869e7b2e7bc54c0800fa6746633a)*

Comment: Thanks kazi for your answer! just another quick one. What if I'm already joining to the table for another data set? I'm already left joined on meter to meter to pull back another field called MAP. I've tried adding on a and clause for table1.METER=table2.mac_address but I'm still pulling mac address through.

Comment: If possible please share your query.

Comment: I've updated the Left join table so you can see what I'm dealing with and I've updated the code to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: what is in NewSerialNumber column? is it METER?

Comment: Sorry, that has been updated now.

Comment: instead of  METER = L_METER AND METER = MAP.mac_address you can try METER = L_METER or METER = MAP.mac_address